# Help explain why (or why not) the solution for a in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\times(n^{1/n}-a)=0$ is 1-2$C$MRB

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

$C$MRB is approximately 0.1878596424620671202485179340542732. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.1878596424620671202485179340542732300559030949001387&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_*Math-)
and [this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=mrb+constant&t=elga01)

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\times(n^{1/n}-a)$ is formally convergent only when $a =1$. However, if you extend the meaning of $\sum$ through "summation methods", whereby series that diverge in one sense converge in another sense (e.g. Cesaro, etc.) you get results for other $a$.
A few years ago it came to me to ask what value of $a$ gives $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\times(n^{1/n}-a)=0\text{ ?}$$(For what value of a is the Levin's u-transform's and Cesàro's sum result 0 considering weak convergence?)

The solution I got surprised me: it was $a=1-2\times C\mathrm{MRB}=0.6242807150758657595029641318914535398881938101997224\ldots$.
Where $C\mathrm{MRB}$ is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\times(n^{1/n}-1)$.
If that's correct can you explain why?

To see this for yourself in Mathematica enter
`FindRoot[NSum[(-1)^n*(n^(1/n) - x), {n, 1, Infinity}], {x, 1}]` where regularization is used so that the sum that formally diverges returns a result that can be interpreted as evaluation of the analytic extension of the series.

I wrote Mathematica to find out what method it used and they wrote the following:

> Hello Marvin,

> Thank you for your email.

> If you do not specify a Method for NSum it will try to choose between the
> EulerMaclaurin or WynnEpsilon methods. In any case, some implicit
> assumptions about the functions you are summing have to be made. If these
> assumptions are not correct, you may get inaccurate answers.
> [http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalEvaluationOfSumsAndProducts.html]

> From the notes on our internel implementations
> [http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html]:

> Numerical Sums and Products

> If the ratio test does not give 1, the Wynn epsilon algorithm is applied to
> a sequence of partial sums or products.

> Otherwise Euler[Dash]Maclaurin summation is used with Integrate or NIntegrate.

[more]
1-2$C$MRB is what I call M2.
Here is the formula for M2 by way of Levin-Type Sequence Transformations: in Maple

`Digits := 20; fsolve(sum((-1)^j*(j^(1/j)-a), j = 1 .. infinity) = 0, a)`,

giving 0.62428071507586575950,

and in Mathematica,

`Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 10000}, FindRoot[NSum[(-1)^j*(j^(1/j) - a), {j, Infinity}], {a, 0.6}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]`,

giving {n -> 0.62428071507608096085}.

There is a discrepancy between the two results, but they do agree that M2 is approximately = 0.624280715076.

Finally let a = M2 = $1-2\times C$MRB = 0.6242807150758... and the two limit-points of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\times(n^{1/n}-M2)$  are +/- $C$MRB with its Levin's u-transform's result being 0. See [here.](http://oeis.org/A173273)

Any explanation of why this is so (or not so) or editing help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does "if you extend of meaning of $\sum$" mean?

Comment: @nik As Euler said and is translated at http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~euler/docs/translations/E352.pdf, "It is necessary to give to the word sum a more extended meaning. We understand the sum to be the numerical value, or analytical relationship which is arrived at according to principles of analysis, that generate the same series for which we seek the sum."
So in my question regularization is used so that the sum that formally diverges returns a result that can be interpreted as evaluation of the analytic extension of the series. I think I'll ad that to the text of the quetion.

Comment: @nik : I would guess it means you're talking about "summation methods", whereby series that diverge in one sense converge in another sense (e.g. Cesaro, etc.).

Comment: @MarvinRayBurns: `@pinging` users who only voted to close this question will not actually notify them. Making an edit to this question will place it in the "Re-open queue" which may result in a quicker re-opening.  (In particular, explicitly adding what type(s) of extension(s) of $\sum$ you are interested in would very very helpful, IMHO.)

Comment: The key is that for any decent summation method $\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^k b=-\frac b2$

Comment: @fedja I did come across something like that in Wikipedia. Would it still be possible to show a proof of why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\times(n^{1/n}-a)=0 \text{ using}\sum_{k\ge 1}(-1)^k b=-\frac b2$?